# How do I get eclipse's web page editor to work?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I installed the eclipse web page editor from the help->updates->Ganymede Update Side-> Web and Java EE Development. - version 2.1.0

Whenever I try to open an html page though, I get the error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.isBlockSelectionModeEnabled()Z

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I ran into this issue as well and it might be caused by the version 3.1 of "Eclipse XML editors and tools" I've seen people mention if they go back to 3.0.4 it works.

Eclipse XML editors and tools is part of the Web Tools Platform and I got the downgraded version here:

http://archive.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.0/R-3.0.4-20090213193639/

Comment: Wow, it seems the actual problem was that the "Eclipse XML editors and tools" were not even installed by the dependencies.  After installing 3.0.4, all is good.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That may be due to a conflict with other plugins you may have installed before.

If you didn't have any other plugins, try accessing your html pages with a fresh installation of an eclipse distro including WTP.
See **[the Java J2EE package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages)** for instance.

Comment: It's rarely a conflict, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError almost always means a version mismatch.